# Finding iFrame Content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to figure out a way to select the iFrame in the following JSFiddle which says 'Test'. The way I'm attempting to do so is as follows but it doesn't seem to be working. I can't select anything using a class/id as the div is dynamically produced in my website.

```js
$('.big-box').each(function(index) 
{
  if ($(this).find("div").find("iframe").contents().find("body").contents().length > 0)
  {
    console.log("Trigger");
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="big-box">
  <iframe>
    Other
  </iframe>
  <div>
    <iframe>
      <body>
        Test
      </body>
    </iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `contents()` after `find("body")`.

[contents()](https://api.jquery.com/contents/) will be used only on the iframe, you don't need it for the other DOM elements.